# Access a .xlsb file in java

Tags: java, excel, jdbc, odbc

I've the below JDBC code. I'm trying to create a `dnsless` connection.

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
public class dummy {
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        System.out.println("-------- Oracle JDBC Connection Testing ------");
        try {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Where is your Oracle JDBC Driver?");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("Oracle JDBC Driver Registered!");
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};DBQ=D:/abc.xls;");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        if (connection != null) {
            System.out.println("You made it, take control your database now!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
        }
    }

}
```

This program is working fine with the below output.

```
-------- Oracle JDBC Connection Testing ------
Oracle JDBC Driver Registered!
You made it, take control your database now!
```

But i need to access a `.xlsb` file, and when i change

```
connection = DriverManager
                    .getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};DBQ=D:/abc.xls;");
```

to

```
connection = DriverManager
                    .getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xlsb)};DBQ=D:/abc.xlsb;");
```

I'm getting the below output with exception.

```
-------- Oracle JDBC Connection Testing ------
Oracle JDBC Driver Registered!
Connection Failed! Check output console
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLDriverConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at dummy.main(dummy.java:19)
```

please let me know how can i fix this, I want to use a `dnsless connection`. Since I've multiple Excel Sheets to work on.

And all my apps are 32bit.

Thanks

Comment: You could try installing the [Access Database Engine](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=13255) and then see if you can use `Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)}`. (Note that you must install the driver with the same "bitness" as the JVM in which your Java app will run: 32-bit or 64-bit.)

Comment: Hi @GordThompson, thanks for poking with these `bitness`, missed that while writing the question, all my applications are 32 bit. Updated my question :)

Comment: @GordThompson, Just curious to know, what is this Access Database Engine, will i need it when i deploy my app? Also can i make DNS less connections with this?

Comment: The Access Database Engine includes components and drivers to work with data in Office applications, including Access databases, Excel documents, plus a couple of other formats (Text and dBASE files). If your app uses it then it would need to be installed on any machine where your app is deployed. And yes, it can be used with DSN-less connections.

Comment: ... also remember that the JDBC-ODBC Bridge has been removed from Java 8, so your deployment strategy would have to ensure that your app was running under a Java 7 (or earlier) JVM.

Comment: I suggest you have a look at Apache POI and read that file directly, this will make you independent of Java version, data sources and Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As its name indicates, the older Excel ODBC driver

```
Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};
```

only works with `.xls` files.

The newer Excel ODBC driver

```
Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};
```

also works with the [Open XML file types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338205%28v=office.12%29.aspx) used by the more recent versions of Excel (2007 and later). The newer Excel driver is included as part of the [Access Database Engine](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=13255) install.